# Use variable as data in apexcharts

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I'm trying to display a chart in apexcharts, and use a variable as the data. When I do this, nothing is displayed. See the following:

```
var message = '[1,4]'
var options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    sparkline: {
      enabled: true,
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: message,
  }],
}   

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

Using the variable `message` as data doesn't work. When I switch the line:

```
data: message,
```

to

```
data: [1,4]
```

it displays correctly. However, I must use a variable. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared message variable as STRING, It is expecting an ARRAY

Please change

```
var message = '[1,4]'
```

to

```
var message = [1,4];
```

Comment: Or `JSON.parse` the string